# Minecraft Crashes After Trying to Teleport an Extreme Distance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried command: `/tp ~ ~6000000000000000000000 ~`.  I teleported, but Minecraft crashed. When I enter my world it crashes. This world is very special for me. How can I fix this? How can I change my position?

Comment: Not sure here, but you've more than likely gone way out of the radius of world generation, meaning that modifying your own player position won't work, since there's corrupt chunks in existence, it causes your game to crash. The only way I'd say to fix this would be to delete said chunks and then move your charachter back. Again though, posting this as a comment since I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

There is an external tool called "NBTExplorer" which can be used to modify the data of a save file. You can use it to edit the player location of that save.

Open NBTExplorer and find **your_save/playerdata/your_uuid/Pos** and edit the values by double-clicking on them. Save the changes and load up your world again.

Comment: I changed my position with NBTExplorer but did't fix.

Comment: The player data of a singleplayer / open-to-lan map is stored in two places. One is the uuid, the other is level.dat/data/player.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of your inventory are not of particular importance to you, you can delete your player data file and you should appear again at spawn when you log in.

Comment: I tried it too but i can't again.

Answer (score 0):

To change your position in singleplayer you have to change the position in level.dat file using NBTExplorer like the other person mentioned, however you don't have to do that in your own player file (that is for multiplayer/lan world I believe).

To change it go to `[world]>level.dat>Data>Player>Pos>[2nd value]`.
Change the second value to a reasonable Y-level and then it should be good.

Oh and don't forget to save since some people (including myself) do that.